# How to merge two objects in Blender

Tags: 3d, models, blender, 3d-meshes

### What I've Done

1. I created a **Cube** object **with Subdivision Surface modifier** in order
   to model a spehere.
2. I created a cuboid object looking like a angled, longish baton.

### What I Want to Do

I want to merge these two objects. So I want to have got just one object - a (cube locking like a) sphere with a baton sticking out on one side. It should look a bit like a head with a throat attached at the bottom.

### How I Want to Do It

- **I don't want to apply the Subdivision Surface modifier** - I want to be
  able to edit my object later on nicely.
- I don't want to have any space between the baton and the sphere. It should be coherent.
- It should be possible without any bad artifices. Everything should be nice.

### My Question

How can I **merge these two objects** nicely? Thanks. - I hope it's clear what I want to describe.

Answer (score 35):

On each object you will choose one or more faces that will be removed. In between these faces will be your connection.

- Select both objects in object mode. Press `Ctrl+J` to join the objects into one. Then enter edit mode and change to face manipulation mode.

  [image]
- Remove the faces that will be joined. Select them and press `X`, remember to delete faces, not vertices.

[image]

- Switch back to Vertex manipulation mode. Join the objects by selecting the corresponding vertices from each object and using `F` to create a new face. For example, in the image below I've selected two of the vertices on the sphere and one on the cuboid. When I press `F` Blender will create a new triangle face there. It also supports quads if the vertices share a common plane. I typically limit the vertex selection to three or four vertices at a time, I tend to think I know where I want the faces to be better than Blender. But you can try selecting all the vertices and see what Blender does for you.

[image]

- Continue the previous step until all faces are joined.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for exerting yourself for such a detailed description - but it's actually not an answer to my question. I wrote: "`What I've Done: I created a cube object with a Subdivision Surface modifier in order to model a spehere.`" But in your initial situation you used a Icosphere instead of a subsurfed Cube. - So you're talking about a very different kind of problem.

Comment: That's what actually want: There should be **`(1)`** a subsurfed Cube (or another kind of mesh which can be subsurfed that way) looking like a sphere and **`(2)`** a cuboid sticking out of that Cube. - I really don't want to use a Icosphere without an Subsurf modifier because I want to **be able to change grade of detailing** later on.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I take some screenshots of my problem? Or do you know what I mean now?

Comment: If you want to attach one object to another, the objects will share modifiers. You can't manipulate the temporary points that are generated by the unapplied subsurface modifier. You could set the cubes subsurf modifier to the minimum level you want, then apply it, that will generate real vertices you can manipulate. Go through the steps I list above, then apply the subsurf modifier to the joined object. There's no way to have two objects joined by vertices created by an unapplied modifier and no way to apply the modifier to only part of the joined object.

Comment: You can always use an isosphere too, it also accepts a subsurface modifier. But whatever you use, if you want to change the grade of detailing, it will affect the entire object, not just the part that was a sphere before joining. If you still want to stick to all the things you've bolded, then **no** it's not possible.

Comment: "`[...] if you want to change the grade of detailing, it will affect the entire object`": That's clear to me, I've never expected anything else.

Comment: "`You could set the cubes subsurf modifier to the minimum level you want, then apply it, that will generate real vertices you can manipulate.`" I thought about that too, but to me it's just a **stopgap**. It would be acceptable in this special, simple case, but it's not nice while working on more complex meshes. I **don't want to deal with a damn tight mesh** of a complex object just because there's a small baton sticking out on one side.

Comment: "`There's no way to have two objects joined by vertices created by an unapplied modifier`" I know, but I thought about creating some more vertices and edges **just on the side** of the mesh where the baton should stick out. But if the mesh is tighter on one side, then my object gets deformed. So I think the mesh I needs to be the same tight on every side of the object in order to create a nice looking sphere. Or is there a way to **prevent deforming**?

Comment: Thanks for giving some thoughts on my problem. - But I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: I suggest expanding your question to include *why* you want to do it this way, perhaps then someone may be able to come up with an entirely different way of doing that avoids the problem you're currently having. As far as I know there's no way to achieve what you want with the limitations you've provided. Good luck.

Comment: You should edit what you have tried and why it didn't work into parts of your your question, not in comments

Comment: @MicroMachine It's 5 years old man. That's when the user was last active as well.

Comment: @Byte56 Oh! I see now. Sorry. Oh well maybe I or someone else can edit this into original Q...

Comment: When I press `Ctrl+J` in object mode with both objects selected, they don't join together.

Answer (score 6):

If the result in the image satisfies you, here's how I achieved it.

1. Subsurfed the initial cube once
2. Created a second cube and scaled it
3. Added a `boolean` modifier to the first cube and chose `union`
4. Selected the second cube as the modifier target object
5. <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> Set the first cube as parent of the second so that both move together when moving the first cube
6. <kbd>Tab</kbd> Entered edit mode on the second cube, <kbd>A</kbd> selected everything and on the <kbd>N</kbd> properties panel I set `Mean Crease` to 1. This makes the second subsurf (see step 8 below) "ignore" the baton
7. <kbd>H</kbd> Hid the second cube. Some times this causes the modifier to get confused and the baton hides altogether, but moving the first cube should refresh the view.
8. Added a second `subsurf` below the `boolean`. This actually merges the object so that your second requirement is fulfilled

[image: Spherebaton]
[image: Setting mean crease to 1 for everything]